# Java occurrence frequency of the first character in an input text using Do/While loop

Tags: java

I am working on my homework assignment and getting stuck at do/while loop. Probably I don't have much understanding as I am still learning.

I am supposed to get the frequency of first Character in the rest of the string.
for example: I am taking Infosys; frequency is 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Input = "";
    int count = 0;

    do {
        char fChar = Input.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.length(); i++)
            if (Input.charAt(i) == fChar) {
                System.out.println("counter:" + count);
                count += 1;
                Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Input");
            } else System.out.println("Its empty");
    } while (!Input.equals(""));
}
```

I am getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 0

I am trying but I know I am making a mistake somewhere and I thought I will ask you guys to assist me find my mistake. Thanks

Comment: You checked the value of `Input` before you gave it a value. You made it an empty string then right after you tried to get the char at position 0 which does not exist because the String is empty.

Comment: You're taking the first char of Input (which should be named input), and Input is an empty string. Hence the exception. Start by writing a method taking a sentence as argument, and call it with a hard-coded sentence. Then, when that works, use a JOptionPane to get the sentence, and pass the result to your working method.

Comment: To expand on what @csm_dev said: `Input` is an empty string, so its length is `0`, therefore index `0` is out of bounds

Comment: I really don't understand the upvotes - I see no research or debugging effort. Not even a Google of the error message or anything.

Comment: Thank you all very much, I appreciate all of your help. 

csm_dev, I have been researching constantly, read my chapter and my module but my main issue was there were no examples of if with do and where loop. If I am posting something here, it means I have not been able to get a clear understanding from anywhere else. Beside, I am still learning so I have no shame in asking and trying :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you assign `""` to your `String`, then try to check `Input.charAt(0)` which is empty.

```
        String input;
        int count = 0;
        do {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Input");
            char firstChar = input.charAt(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                if (input.charAt(i) == firstChar) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
            count = 0;
        } while (!input.isEmpty());
```

**Note:** you'll still need to do a check if the String is empty, otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot and made me look at what I was doing wrong. I completed the assignment.

I have added break point to display another text of string in case someone enters blank.